# GCC optimization flag problems

Tags: c, gcc, enums

I am having a problem with some C code built with gcc compiler. The code in question has an enum, whose values are used as cases in a switch statement to configure an object. Fairly standard stuff.

When I compile the code using the `-O0` option flag, everything builds and runs correctly no problem. However, when the flag is set to `-O2` the code no longer works as expected.

When I step through the code and put a watch on the local variables, the enum, which should be only be one of three enum values, is actually -104! This causes the program to fail to configure the object.

Has anyone encountered this before who could provide some guidance? I haven't encountered this before and would appreciate if someone could explain why the compiler does this so I can make any necessary changes.

Snippet of code in question:

```
value = 0u;

switch(test_config) { 
    case DISABLE:
        break;

    case INTERNAL:
        value = 1u;
        break;

    case EXTERNAL:
        value = 2u;
        break;

    default:
        valid = FALSE;
        break;
} 

if (valid) { 
    configure_test(value);
}
```

Enum in question:

```
typedef enum  {
    DISABLE,
    INTERNAL, 
    EXTERNAL
} test_config_t;
```

This is the code that is causing the problem. I initially didn't include it because I didn't want the question to be please fix my code, rather I have been googling looking for reasons why gcc optimisation flags would produce different results for the same piece of code and haven't found anything particularly helpful. Also I am not at my computer and had to type this on my phone which also doesn't help. So I came here because there are experts here who know way more than me that could point me in the right direction.

Some more info that I probably should have included. The code runs on hardware which also might be the problem and I am looking into that as well. When ran from FSBL the code works with -O0, but not with -O2. So it may be hardware, but then I don't know why it works one way not the other.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: yes, code containing buggy statements/undefined behaviour can break when using optimization options. Don't post your code but rather a [mcve].

Comment: Definitely UB. But we can't know why out of thin air.

Comment: The problem is *not* in the code you have shown in your last edition. It is probably in its caller !

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Comment: where (and to what value) is the variable: `test_config` being set? please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You don't give enough details (since your question don't show any actual code, it should have some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) but you very probably have some [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)  and you should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

Remember that [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) or [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) (like most [programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)) is defined by an *explicit* specification (not only by the concrete behaviour observed on your code) written in English and *partly* defining the runtime behaviour of a valid C program. Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

I strongly recommend reading Lattner's blog [*What Every C programmer should know about Undefined Behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) before even touching or compiling your source code.

I recommend at least compiling with (nearly) all warnings and debug info, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, then improve the code to get no warnings, and run it under the `gdb` debugger and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Read more about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You may also use (temporarily) some sanitizer [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html), notably `-fsanitize=undefined` and `-fsanitize=address`. You could also add `-std=gnu99` and `-pedantic` to your compiler flags. Notice that `gdb` [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) are a very useful debugger feature to find why a value has changed or is unexpected.

When you compile for release or for benchmarking with optimizations enabled, keep also the warning flags (so compile with `gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra`); optimizations might give extra warnings which you should also correct. BTW, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) accepts both `-O2` and `-g` at the same time.

When you observe such issues, question first your own code before suspecting the compiler
 <sup>(because compilers are very well tested; I found only one compiler bug in almost 40 years of programming).</sup>

Comment: You also want `-pedantic` and some `-std` option such as `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: One could want to use GNU extensions, which `-pedantic` forbids.

Comment: `-pedantic` doesn't forbid GNU extensions.

Comment: @melpomene: this is not what the [warning options of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) documentation says

Comment: Yeah, sloppy wording on my part. It depends on what is meant by "forbid" (`-pedantic` doesn't error out, it just emits warnings) and "GNU extensions" (e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords says "*`-pedantic` and other options cause warnings for many GNU C extensions*", i.e. it doesn't warn for all of them, just many).

Comment: Thanks. I will try sanitize to see if I can figure this out. I am already using all the other options you provided, except using `-std=c99` instead.

Comment: And you certainly need to use the debugger. watchpoints should be really helpful.